# Error when using MERGE UPDATE with a uniqueidentifier data type

Tags: sql-server, merge, uniqueidentifier

I have 2 table that have a column with a data type of uniqueidentifier. When using the MERGE statement it will INSERT rows with no problem. The UPDATE part fails with the error `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`

I have searched and could not find an answer to why this happens. I have tested this on SQL2017 and SQL2019, same error. Here is a simple script that shows the error.

```
DECLARE @T2 TABLE(ID_var VARCHAR(36), ID_unique uniqueidentifier);
INSERT INTO @T1 ( ID_var ) VALUES ('0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0');
INSERT INTO @T2 ( ID_var ) SELECT NEWID();
INSERT INTO @T2 ( ID_var, ID_unique) VALUES ('0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0', '0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0')

-- This works
UPDATE @T2
SET ID_unique = NEWID()
WHERE ID_unique IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM @T1;
SELECT * FROM @T2;

MERGE @T1 AS t1
USING (SELECT ID_var, ID_unique FROM @T2) AS t2
ON t1.ID_var = t2.ID_var
-- Insert NEW Rows -- this works
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (ID_var, ID_unique)
VALUES (ID_var, ID_unique)
-- Update CHANGED Rows -- This fails
WHEN MATCHED AND COALESCE(t1.ID_unique,'') <> COALESCE(t2.ID_unique,'')
THEN UPDATE
SET
ID_unique = t2.ID_unique
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*
;

SELECT * FROM @T1;
```

Does anyone know of documentation of why this happens or how to get around it.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the `MERGE`. `''` is not a valid `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: If you want an empty `uniqueidentifier` try `CAST(0x0 AS uniqueidentifier)`